# Solving a two cubic equations system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, cubics

I have this system of two equations I'm trying to solve:

$$-(1+\alpha) x^3 + (\alpha y +1) x^2 - (1+\alpha) \beta^2 x + \alpha\beta ^2 y = 0$$
$$-(1+\alpha) y^3 + (\alpha x +\epsilon) y^2 - (1+\alpha) \beta^2 y + \alpha\beta ^2 x = 0$$

It is easy to see that (0,0) is one solution of this problem, but I'm having trouble in finding the others.

Any ideas?

Comment: are $(x,y)$ the variables?

Comment: the solution Looks very complicated

Comment: If $ε≠1$, $x=y$ is not solution except x=y=0.

Comment: this is originally a system of two first order differential equations, for which I want to find the equilibrium points.